# XCode Library Search Paths Slash Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I am adding a library at a custom path, a non-recursive relative path for e-g

"$(SRCROOT)/CrittercismSDK-crashonly3.3.4"

When I drag and drop or add library via **Build Phases> Link Binary With Libraries** it auto add a slash "\" and my path becomes

\"$(SRCROOT)/CrittercismSDK-crashonly3.3.4\"

I have large number of libraries and its hard to remove slashes. It happens every time I add a library or framework. Please tell me what is the issue and how I can resolve it.

[image]

I am using Xcode version 5.0.2